# Pending breakpoint in windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

Remote debugging is not possible & need to debug my code for an issue not reproducible on my system.
I can set a pending breakpoint in gdb on linux. I need something similar on windbg or on windows platform as I cannot share the source file but I need to break in the file at particular line in order to debug.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by pending breakpoint  ?
does the module in which the function resides loaded dynamically and you need to set a breakpoint beforehand ?

if yes then use bu breakpoints

```
bu myfoomodule!myblahfunction
```

this will load the symbols when the module is loaded and set a breakpoint as and when needed

```
0:000> lm m help*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name

<<<<<<<<<<<< no results here
```

lets confirm by forcefully realoding symbols and checking for the existence of 
this module

```
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules

0:000> lm m help*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name

again no results we cant set a regular breakpoint 
our breakpoint needs to be set using unresolved breakpoint    
lets set it 

0:000> bu HelpPaneProxy!DllMain
let us check 

0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear u             0001 (0001) (HelpPaneProxy!DllMain)         
     lets continue 

0:000> g
ModLoad: 77ac0000 77adf000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 76f90000 7705c000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
un needed mod load display cut off XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ModLoad: 67d80000 67d91000   C:\Windows\System32\HelpPaneProxy.dll

bingo our breakpoint hit on the module load triggered after clicking help in calc 

Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=00000001 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=0025cfa8
eip=67d84700 esp=0025ce7c ebp=0025ced8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
HelpPaneProxy!DllMain:
67d84700 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```